# Контекст, создаваемый в репозитории(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть Mobile area и Account controller в нем

Вот код

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private AccountRepositoryEntities repoEntities; //The desktop trackerweb repository
    private Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository mobileRepo;
    private IdentityUserManager userManager;
    private IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private Dictionary dictionary;

    public AccountController(TraxgoDB context) : base()
    {
        repoEntities = new AccountRepositoryEntities();
        mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository(context);
    }
}
```

Контекст передается в контроллер в качестве параметра

Нужно сделать так, чтобы контекст создавался в репозитории

И контроллер выглядел так

```
public AccountController() : base()
{
    repoEntities = new AccountRepositoryEntities();
    mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository();
}
```

Собственно код самого `Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository`

```
public sealed class AccountRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public AccountRepository(TraxgoDB context) : base(context) { }

    public Site TryGetCustomSite(string hostName)
    {
        var site = context.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => hostName.Contains(s.HostName));
        if (site != null && site.HostName != "traxgo")
            return site;
        return null;
    }

    public CultureInfo UpdateCustomerLanguage(int customerID, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TraxgoDB(TraxgoDBRights.ReadWrite))
        {
            var customer = ctx.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == customerID);
            var currentCultureInfo = customer.Language.GetCultureInfo();

            if (currentCultureInfo != culture)
            {
                customer.Language = culture.GetLanguage();
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            return culture;
        }
    }
}
```

И код BaseRepository

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected TraxgoDB context { get; }

    protected BaseRepository(TraxgoDB context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Перед тем, как спрашивать "как" давайте лучше спросим у вас "зачем"? Вот вы хотите "сделать так, чтобы контекст создавался в репозитории" -- а зачем? У вас сейчас худо-бедно, но DI на конструкторе, а хотите вы вернуться к хардкоду.

Comment: Дело в том что это не я хочу вернуться к хардкоду, а требование со стороны заказчика. Я понимаю что сейчас DI на конструкторе@AK

Comment: Ну положим. Что тогда удерживает от того, чтобы в конструкторах репозиториев (или в базовом один раз) написать `this.Context = new DataContext();`? Кроме того, зачем открывать контекст ctx если у вас есть context из базового репозитория?

Comment: Но я так понимаю пожно от инъекции зависимостей избавится таким образом тоже?

`public AccountController() : base()
        {
            using (TraxgoDB ctx = new TraxgoDB())
            {
                repoEntities = new AccountRepositoryEntities();
                mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository(ctx);
            }
        }`@AK

Comment: Нет, неправильно понимаете. Вы только что три раза написали new в коде. Встраивание зависимостей (dependency injection, DI) относится к передаче зависимостей класса или метода в виде параметров вместо «зашивания» в код этих связей через new или статические вызовы.

Comment: Но у меня задание убрать параметры с контроллера.

Возможно я конечно неправильно понимаю задание, но звучит оно так:

so to start with
each controller constructor with arguments, should have its argumentts removed
for example: public AccountController(TraxgoDB context)  -> public AccountController() 
 mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository(context);  -> mobileRepo = new Domain.Repository.Mobile.AccountRepository(); 
because we want the context to be instantiated within the repository @AK

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65729/discussion-between-mark-spencer-and-a-k).